# Can't start ubuntu terminal after using Docker/Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, ubuntu, terminal, wsl-2

I'm receiving the following errors when trying to open my Ubuntu terminal (I'm using WSL2):

```
<3>WSL (18709) ERROR: ConfigUpdateLanguage:2950: fopen(/etc/default/locale) failed 5
<3>WSL (18709) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:577: execvpe /usr/bin/zsh failed 5
<3>WSL (18709) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:586: Create process not expected to return

[process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]
```

A quick google search turned up some results related to Docker (but nothing directly related to my issue), so I'm wondering if the fact I used Docker recently (yesterday) has something to do with it. Any help/ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: A search for me (`wsl fopen(/etc/default/locale) failed 5`) turned up: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9171 One person solved it by exporting the image and reimporting it. You could also try the whole "turn it off and back on again" by running `wsl.exe --shutdown` in Powershell to forcibly shut it down and then start it back up.

Comment: the simple `wsl.exe --shutdown` worked! Thank you @MagnieMozios!

Comment: Awesome! Made it an actual answer for others who might run into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the whole "turn it off and back on again" by running `wsl.exe --shutdown` in Powershell to forcibly shut it down and then start it back up.